# How to provide an optional instance to Bogus Faker in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, faker, bogus

I have my own static helper to generate fake instances of my domain records/classes.

Does Bogus have the ability to use a *provided instance* or fake a new instance if there was none, provided?

Here's some code to explain.

```
public static Foo CreateAFoo(int? id = null, string? name = null, AThing? aThing = null)
{
    var foo = new Faker<Foo>()
        .RuleFor(x => x.Id, f => id ?? <let faker generate one normally>)
        .RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => name ?? <let faker generate one normally>)
        .RuleFor(x => x.Thing, f= > aThing ?? <let faker generate one normally>)
    ; 
}
```

Is this possible?

I was thinking of just letting Faker generate the entire thing .. and POST generation, overwriting any properties with my values if they exist. Problem with this answer is that my object (in this case, `Foo`) is a *record* and therefore I would need to instantiate *an entirely new one*.

So .. is this possible? Not sure if the `OrDefault` or `OrNull` extension methods might help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrDefault` and `OrNull` don't help you in this case. They randomly assign the `default(T)` value (you provide) or `null` at a 50% probability (which you can change) respectively.

You would need to set up a Bogus generator for `AThing`. It doesn't know how to do it automatically.

```cs
public static Foo CreateAFoo(int? id = null, string? name = null, AThing? aThing = null)
{
    var testAThing = new Faker<AThing>();
        //.RuleFor(a => a.Property, f => <>)

    var foo = new Faker<Foo>()
        .RuleFor(x => x.Id, f => id ?? <let faker generate one normally>)
        .RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => name ?? <let faker generate one normally>)
        .RuleFor(x => x.Thing, f= > aThing ?? testAThing.Generate())
    ; 
}
```

Or look into using [AutoBogus](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus)

```cs
var aThing = AutoFaker.Generate<AThing>();
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @hank ! this is great info! How do I handle the `Id` and `Name`, above? also with `.Generate()` ?

Comment: Oh I thought you were omitting for brevity because you had something. You can check the bogus C# example here: https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#the-great-c-example It'll be something along the lines of `f => f.Name.Generate()` for generating names and `f => f.Random.Int()` for ints.